# Why variable value is different incase of var and let in setTimeout

Tags: javascript

While practicing JavaScript, I came across with one doubt I am printing variable i value using var and using let keyword and both the time getting different result but unable to understand why I need some explanation for this??

Declaring `i` as `let`:

```
<script>
(function timer() {
  for (let i = 0; i <= 5; i++) { 
    setTimeout(
      function clog() {
        console.log(i);
      }, i * 1000
    ); 
  }
})();
</script>
```

The output is a count from 0 to 5: [image]

Declaring `i` as `var`, on the other hand:

```
<script>
(function timer() {
  for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i++) { 
    setTimeout(
      function clog() {
        console.log(i);
      }, i * 1000
    ); 
  }
})();
</script>
```

The output is 6 times a 6: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of globally (var) or block scoped (let) value processing of javascript.

In var, variable i is globally changing and the loop finishes before settimeout function runs, so the i becomming 6 globally and console log writes yo it as 6.

In let, for every loop iteration there is an i variable belongs only that scope and settimeout function takes it, so the even if the loop finish it's job console log writes local varible i as 0,1,2,3,4,5.

I hope i tell myself correctly.

ref: [Javascript MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#:%7E:text=let%20allows%20you%20to%20declare,function%20regardless%20of%20block%20scope.)

Answer (score 4):

The reason is simple. `let` is block scoped. It means that when you get out of the scope of your for loop, it does not exist. `var` scope is wider. What happens here is that the for loop increments `i` 5 times, then gets out of the loop with `i = 6` before the first setTimeout triggers (in less than 1 second) with a global scope. The `i` declared with `let` is from the function scope, while the `i` declared with var is from the outer scope

Difference between let and var:
[What is the difference between "let" and "var"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/what-is-the-difference-between-let-and-var)

Answer (score 1):

With `for` loop, each iteration has its own **scope**.

1. In the case of `let` as its `block scope` each iteration will have its own `i` variable and its value will be closure in the `setTimeout`, so each `setTimeout` will output the correct index
2. In the case of `var` as it's a `functional scope`, each iteration will override the previous one, and at the time of execution of the `setTimeout` the value of `i` will be `6` at the end of the iteration, will be logged in all setTimeout callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

The scope of `i` is different when using `let` and when using `var`

Here:

```
for(let i=0;i<=5;i++){ // i will not be available outside of the block below

setTimeout(
function clog(){
console.log(i)

},i*1000 ); 
// mentionning the variable i will cause a Reference error starting from here
```

Whereas with `var`, `i` gets hoisted, and defined without a value at the beginning of current the function's block, at the end of the loop `i` still exists, and has been mutated, so by the time the `setTimeout` callback is triggered, the loop will be already finished and `i` will have its final value, which is the first value not matching the looping condition (i.e. `6`).